# The ParentDataWidget Positioned wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a RenderObject

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the error on this and what does it mean? i am trying to fix some overflow error on this but cant understand what does it mean

Error Message

> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
> DecoratedBox ← Container ← Positioned ← SizedBox ← Row ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Padding ← Container ← ⋯

```
class AbandonedMoney extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1, top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20,
            vertical: 20,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFF6692F),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 58,
                height: 60,
                child: Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white24,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset("Assets/svg/handmoney.svg")),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 70),
                    child: AutoSizeText(
                      "\$1122k",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  AutoSizeText(
                    "Abandoned from 1396 carts",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white60,
                      fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "- 948%",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFFF6692F),
                    fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to fix the text which is in the center of the container and the below text both text should start on certain point and if id add more number the text position is changing thats the issue

Comment: Can you include a image that you are trying to archive?

Comment: Please share the complete sample code along with the complete error.

Comment: Yeah let me Post it

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Kindly Check it Bro

Comment: what is the parent of `AbandonedMoney`?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is coming because from `Stack`. Its children require positional widget. In your case, you have one inside Row which is not suitable. You can check more about [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

You don't need to use `Stack` the approach you are using. Therefore, `Positinoned` widget won't be needed.  I have included comment where I've modified and play with this and encourage checking about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).

```dart
class AbandonedMoney extends StatelessWidget {
  const AbandonedMoney({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1, top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFFF6692F),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, //play with this
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 58,
            height: 60,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white24,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              // child: SvgPicture.asset("Assets/svg/handmoney.svg"),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //play with this
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, //play with this
            children: const [
              Text(
                "\$1122k",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center, //play with this
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Abandoned from 1396 carts",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center, //play with this
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white60,
                  fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "- 948%",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFF6692F),
                fontFamily: 'Circular Std',
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```